# What does the HTTPS server verify when it asks for a client certificate?

Tags: tls, certificates

I assume that the only thing the server checks is whether the IP on the certificate matches the one for the current TCP/IP connection and that the certificate is signed by an authority the server trusts. Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

> I assume that the only thing the server checks, is that wether the IP on the certificate matches the one for the current TCP/IP connection, ...

That is very likely a thing the server does not check. Client certificates at least for HTTPS are usually not issued for a domain or IP, but for a user - because they are used to authenticate a user and not a system.

> ... that the certificate is signed by an authority the server trusts

This should be checked.

Additionally one might check for a specific subject of the certificate or the web application might decide based on the subject which user this is.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to verifying the information in the certificate and the signature on the certificate, the server verifies that the client has possession of the private key that corresponds with the public key in the client certificate.